# Android device Ethernet and Wi-Fi network bridge

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, ethernet, bridge

I have an Android smart home device that has both ethernet connection and Wi-Fi. The ethernet is connected to the SIP Intercom network (10.0.1.100) and the Wi-Fi is connected to my home router (192.168.1.x).

Is it possible to create a bridge so that I can have network access from my router to the SIP Intercom?